# Jquery table sorter cell height problems with pager

Tags: jquery, cell, tablesorter, pager

Having a problem with jquery table sorter and pager plugin.

All works fine, but if i have say a 'description' column, and it's larger than the the other cells (expands dynamically) how can i get the pager plugin to stick to the bottom of the new table?

My code is at home right now, but here is a sample of the 2 together.

http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-pager.html

In that example, say every '100' is denoted as "100 and this is alot of extra writing that will eventually wrap around to a new row within certain entries in this table"

Do i have to make every cell uniformly big? (cause some may be quite bigger than others) thanks

Comment: Hi Glen, I've used the tablesorter with large cells (multi-line) and it didnt seem to be an issue. What's not working?

Comment: Hey dave, i did some more digging. This code solved it, thanks though.
.tablesorterPager({ 
                                        container: $("#pager"), 
                                        positionFixed: false 
                                });

Comment: Hi Glen, if you've found the answer yourself, can I suggest you post it as an answer and "tick" it - that way, your "accepted" score goes up and this no longer looks like an unsolved question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.tablesorterPager({ container: $("#pager"), positionFixed: false });

Change false to true